# Jquery:how to get the values from the specific class based on its parent class's style?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the values belonging to a specific class "file-name" where its parent class "no-file" has style "display:block". I dont want the values from the class "no-file" that has style "display:none". Below is the structure -

```
    <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:block;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="has-file">
            <span class="file-name">abc.jpg</span>
        </div>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:none;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="has-file">
            <span class="file-name">def.png</span>
        </div>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:none;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:block;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What did you try until now ?

Comment: $('<div>').html(uploaded_file_content).find(".file-name").parent(".no-file").css("display","block").text(); where uploaded_file_content has the html() result of this whole table structure

Answer (score 2):

This should do that for you:

```
$('.no-file:visible .file-name').each(function() { 
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/sWw2x/

The `:visible` selector will filter out any `no-file` divs that have `display:none`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard. In my case, I should be using like - $('<div>').html(uploaded_file_content).find('.no-file:visible .file-name').each(function(){});  but when I use this syntax it does not seem to work. Can you elaborate the solution which is appropriate to my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector as following

```
$('div.no-file:visible .file-name').each(function() { 
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: When I use the visible selector, it is not going inside this each loop.